# Does the POSIX module in the standard Perl distribution work in Win32/64?

Tags: perl, winapi, cross-platform, standards, posix

I was wondering whether using POSIX.pm would make my Perl code less cross platform. From reading the documentation it's not very clear how well it's supported on Win32/64 Perl implementations.

*Is it wise to rely use POSIX.pm if one cares about portable code?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.xav.com/perl/lib/POSIX.html) says it does